# I need to validate that an index is valid of a user entered string

Tags: java

When a user enters a word they then are prompt to enter the first and second index of a substring. I have that much sorted but when I try to validate that the index entered with my if statements below I am getting errors regarding those if statements,

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputString;

        int startIndex;
        int endIndex;

        System.out.println("Enter a string : ");
        inputString = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the first index of the substring : ");
        startIndex = scanner.nextInt();

        if (int startIndex > inputSting.length) {
            System.out.println("Index is not in string length, try again.");
        }


        System.out.println("Enter the second index of the substring : ");
        endIndex = scanner.nextInt();

        if (int endIndex > inputSting.length) {
            System.out.println("Index is not in string length, try again.");
        } 

        char[] ch = new char[endIndex - startIndex + 1];
        inputString.getChars(startIndex, endIndex + 1, ch, 0);

        System.out.println("Output : " + String.valueOf(ch));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the errors you get .

Comment: Is it the missing `r` in `inputSting`? Could you show us the error messages, please? Could be the missing `()` after `length` in the `if` conditions, too... Oh, I see an `int` in the conditions, which really shouldn't be there. Have you done any tutorials concerning `if´ statements in Java? Sorry, but yours are totally wrong.

Comment: why int in if statement?

Comment: // here is chanes I have made but I wanted to force the user to make a valid index input and not let them go any futher....                
            System.out.println("Enter the first index of the substring : ");
        startIndex = scanner.nextInt();
        
          if ( startIndex > inputString.length()) {
         System.out.println("Index is not in string length, try again.");
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is definitely not a Java language.

**First:**

```
if (int startIndex > inputSting.length) { .. }
```

You cannot declare variable neither inside `if` statement nor in compare expression, moreover the variable `startIndex` already exists.

**Second:**

`inputSting` variable does not exists and it surely do not have property `length`. Probably typo of `inputString` + string have method `length()` not the property.

Comment: I have mad the changes but how would I force a user to enter the correct int inputs and not let them go any further until the index are in range?

Answer (score 0):

Change the following :

`int startIndex` to `startIndex` ,

`int endIndex` to `endIndex` ,

`inputSting.length` to `inputString.length()`

So fixed code,

```
 public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputString="";
        int startIndex;
        int endIndex;

        System.out.println("Enter a string : ");
        inputString = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the first index of the substring : ");
        startIndex = scanner.nextInt();

        if ( startIndex > inputString.length()) {
            System.out.println("Index is not in string length, try again.");
        }


        System.out.println("Enter the second index of the substring : ");
        endIndex = scanner.nextInt();

        if ( endIndex > inputString.length()) {
            System.out.println("Index is not in string length, try again.");
        }
        char[] ch = new char[endIndex - startIndex + 1];
        inputString.getChars(startIndex, endIndex + 1, ch, 0);
        System.out.println("Output : " + String.valueOf(ch));
    }
 }
```

Comment: same thing mentioned in comment :)